# How to create TEMPORARY TABLE in mysql without indexes or keys?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    firstname varchar(20),
    lastname varchar(20),
    UNIQUE KEY unique_lstanme (lastname)
);
```

create temporary:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE person_tmp LIKE person;
SHOW INDEX FROM person_tmp;
```

Result: shows the unique key. Why? I always thought `TEMPORARY` tables are created without indexes?

Can I prevent this, or would I have to drop the index explicit on the temp table? Is there a sql command that can drop *any* existing indexes on the temp table without having to name them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql temporary tables can have indexes and the `create temporary table ... like ...` does preserve indexes, there is nothing you can do about it.

Use [create temporary table ... select ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) statement instead with a `limit 0` clause because

> CREATE TABLE ... SELECT does not automatically create any indexes for you. This is done intentionally to make the statement as flexible as possible. If you want to have indexes in the created table, you should specify these before the SELECT statement.

So, your statement would look something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE person_tmp
AS SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 0;
```